# My images are not loading in order in my table view

Tags: swift

I have an iOS app that has an events section where users can post events and attach a flyer image. everything works except two mages show up on top no matter what I do. And I have programmed the app to show the most current post at the top of the table view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
eventsDatabaseHandle = eventsRef?.child("Church Events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in
    let eventPost = snaphot.value as! [String: Any]
    var event = Event(title: eventPost["eventtitle"] as! String,
                      timestamp: eventPost["eventdate"] as! String,
                      location: eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String,
                      image: nil)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: eventPost["ImageUrl"] as! String)!) { data, _, error in

        if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
            event.image = image
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.events.append(event)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

})
```

Comment: Why not use the pre-built sort function and sort it based off of time added?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method?

```
event.image = UIImage(data: image)
```

If you tried this method, there may be an error :

```
eventPost["ImageUrl"]
```

Check with the name in the database.

Comment: new to swift tried to make the changes you recommended, but no success